# I can't assign my getKey names to my list with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have created the same values for different keynames because I cannot create different values from the same keyname. But I can't get my list on firebase when I'm taking my data. I can't use it when I get on my list. I'm getting a debug error.

```
ArrayList<Integer> deneme = new ArrayList<>();
```

//I've defined my list above all of them.

...

```
if(checkModel.isSelected() == true)
                                    {
                                        map.put(checkModel.getName().substring(8),true);
                                        reference.setValue(map);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        map.put(checkModel.getName().substring(8),false);
                                        reference.setValue(map);
                                    }
```

..
I get my data from class 1 or 0 to add to firebase. Sample:
Episode 1 - 1
Episode 2 - 1
Episode 3 - 1

---

```
 public void check(String seasonNo) {

        DatabaseReference ref;

        ref = database.getReference();

        ref.child("Users/"+user.getUid().toString()+"/Watched/"+seriesTitle+"/Season/"+seasonNo)
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                String st = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    int no = Integer.parseInt(st);

                    if(!deneme.contains(no))
                    {
                        deneme.add(no);
                    }

                    checkModelTestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

---

Comment: Please tell us what error you are getting. Also, `for(int i=0; i<kv.size(); < i++)` should be changed to `for(int i=0; i<kv.size(); i++)`

Comment: I am only getting debug error, so the application does not open.

Comment: what error are you getting in the IDE? It should still give you some sort of a message even if its a compile time error message

Comment: I pulled the function in, but this time I can't call my list from another place outside. (edited codes)

Comment: Can you be more speciic? What do you mean by "outside"

Comment: Please add the error that you get and indicate the exact line of code at which it occurs. Please also responde with @AlexMamo